# fprintf prints strange integers

Tags: c, printf

I would expect the code below to produce a file named stackexchangeiscool.txt and write

```
Hello!
I changed my mind: 17291729
```

But it doesn't. It produces a file named stackexchangeiscool.txt that contains the text

```
Hello!
I changed my mind: 17293748407
```

This code sure doesn't make sense; it is part of a larger code where I have strange problems.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE * file = NULL;
    
    file = fopen("stackexchangeiscool.txt","w");
    
    int n = 1729;   
    
    char myFirstString[] = "This is a string.";
    
    fprintf(file, "Hello!\n");
    
    sprintf(myFirstString, "I changed my mind: %d", n);
    
    fprintf(file, "%s", myFirstString);
    fprintf(file, "%d", n);

    fclose(file);
    
    return(0);
}
```

EDIT: A comment below suggested that the problem might come from the fact that myFirstString is too short to contain the new string with the integer in it. However, when I remove the

```
fprintf(file, "%d", n);
```

I get

```
Hello!
I changed my mind: 1729
```

So myFirstString seems to be able to contain the string and the integer.

Comment: If I remove fprintf(file, "%d", n); it prints Hello!
I changed my mind: 1729 which is supposed to be the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, `myFirstString` only has enough room for 18 characters, but you're attempting to copy ~23 characters in. This means you're writing off the end of the array. I think what's happening is `n` is stored directly after `myFirstString` in memory, and by writing off the end of the array, you're "clobbering" `n`.

Make sure the array is large enough ahead of time so that everything can fit:

```
char myFirstString[100] = "This is a string.";
```

Here, I'm making it an arbitrarily large `100` length. You can either set it to an arbitrary fixed-length like this, or calculate the length you need and `malloc` it. Either way, you need to ensure that you have enough memory to work with before attempting to copy data.

Comment: @Plop Use `snprintf()` so you can limit the length and can make sure you avoid buffer overflows (which would cause undefined behaviour (UB)).